# Complex Join Sql query With timer

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, cron

i have 3 tables

logs

```
|id| channel_id | date | content_id |
|1 | 3          | <ts> | 1          |
|1 | 3          | <ts> | 2          |
|1 | 4          | <ts> | 4          |
```

channels

```
|id|  channel_id | limit_repeat_time    | limit_timer | limit_count |  last_update 
|1 | 3           | 60                   | 1440        | 50          |  <timestamp>
|1 | 4           | 60                   | 1440        | 50          |  <timestamp>
```

queue

```
|id| channel_id  | content_id
|1 | 3           |   1
|1 | 3           |   2
|1 | 4           |   4
```

I have a crontab checking this tables and loops and result me list of channels i have to update;

Channels have few options 
1) limit_repeat time : this mean this cron cannot update this channel less than this min; exc : if this one is 60 you can only update this channel every hour.
2) limit_timer and limit_count this is a whole limit count. Like; limit_timer = 1440 limit_count = 50 this is mean you can add 50 content maximum per day (1440 min)

What i need is 
I want to find channels not updated in  and didnt insterted more then  content in

My cron is set to every minute, so i want to run this query every minute and update channels are needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `content_id` column stand for? It's amount of content added to channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. It selects records from `queue` that fullfil the two criteria:

1) `DATE_ADD(MAX(l.date), INTERVAL ch.limit_repeat_time MINUTE)<=NOW()` - check if the last record in `log` table is at least `ch.limit_repeat_time` minutes older than the current system time.

2) `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs l1
        WHERE DATE(l1.date) = DATE(NOW())
        AND l1.channel_id=q.channel_id )
   <=ch.limit_count`

ensures that there is no more than `ch.limit_count` records for that particular `channel` in `logs` table for the present day.

In your example your ID fields are a bit chaotic - allways equals to 1, I do not believe this is the real data. Also do not see why `Channels` table has `channel_id` and  `id`. It seems not necessary to me.

The whole select:

```
SELECT q.channel_id, q.content_id

FROM `queue` AS q
INNER JOIN `channels` ch
ON ch.channel_id=q.channel_id 
LEFT JOIN `logs` l 
   ON l.channel_id=q.channel_id 

GROUP BY q.channel_id, q.content_id, ch.limit_repeat_time, ch.limit_count
HAVING (MAX(l.date) IS NULL OR
DATE_ADD(MAX(l.date), INTERVAL ch.limit_repeat_time MINUTE)<=NOW())
AND
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `logs` l1
        WHERE DATE(l1.date) = DATE(NOW())
        AND l1.channel_id=q.channel_id ),0)
<ch.limit_count
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ce27/1).

This query does not cover the situation, when you have already 49 items processed and there are 10 new items in the queue - all the 10 new queue items would be returned then, so you have to perform an additional check of `limit_count` when adding new items.

Also you can simplify this query if you allways update your `channel.last_update` atribute after inserting new records.

```
SELECT q.channel_id, q.content_id
FROM `queue` AS q
INNER JOIN `channels` ch ON ch.channel_id=q.channel_id 
WHERE ch.last_update IS NULL OR 
      DATE_ADD(ch.last_update, INTERVAL ch.limit_repeat_time MINUTE)<=NOW()
AND
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `logs` l1
        WHERE DATE(l1.date) = DATE(NOW())
        AND l1.channel_id=q.channel_id )
      <ch.limit_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are explaining what you are trying to do very well, however this will get you are looking for.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    `channels` AS c
WHERE
    DATE_ADD(c.`last_update`, INTERVAL c.`limit_repeat_time` MINUTE) > NOW()
AND c.limit_count < (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        `logs` AS l
    WHERE
        l.`channel_id` = 3
    AND l.`date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL c.`limit_timer` MINUTE) AND NOW()
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, im sorry about my english. On this sql code queue is missing sql should check count at queue is there anything at queue belong to user.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve limit_time using this if

```
DECLARE limit_time_var integer;
SELECT limit_repeat_time INTO limit_time_var FROM channels 
       WHERE id=1 and channel_id=3;

if (((hour(curtime())* 60) + (minute(curtime()))) % limit_repeat_time = 0)
    then
    --Query time and count according to that day interval. I couldn't understand what is log and queue. If it is smaller than you expect then insert.
end if;
```